# $(window).scrollTop(value) is not working properly

Tags: jquery, scroll

#### First

```
$(window).scrollTop(value);  // this does not work at first fire. after first, it works well.
```

#### second

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $(window).scrollTop(scrollVal); // this works well
}, 100);
```

I can't understand why the first one is not working properly :(
Is there anyone who know this phenomenon?

thanks for reading.

Comment: Are you calling it after the document is ready?

Comment: So it's in a `$(document).ready()` callback? I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: code seems to be fine. Are you sure you are passing the correct value.